# Terraform how to access the elements

Tags: terraform

This is defined in my tfvars.

```
common_firewall_rules = {
        "IP_Orange" = {
                name             = "Orange"
                start_ip_address = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
                end_ip_address   = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
        },
        "OBS1" = {
                name             = "OBS2"
                start_ip_address = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
                end_ip_address   = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
        },
        "OBS2" = {
                name             = "OBS2"
                start_ip_address = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
                end_ip_address   = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
        }
}
```

Now while creating a Azure Analysis service I need to add firewall rules.
There is no separate provider for doing this, has to go in the

I have would semi-hardcode the 3 rules. But can't get it coded
This is what I do (I've already tried several versions :-( )

```
ipv4_firewall_rule {
    name        = var.common_firewall_rules[0].name.value
    range_start = var.common_firewall_rules[0].start_ip_address.value
    range_end   = var.common_firewall_rules[0].end_ip_address.value
  }
```

And this is what I get

```
│ Error: Invalid index
│ 
│   on _modules/das/others/as_create/main.tf line 48, in resource "azurerm_analysis_services_server" "as":
│   48:     name        = var.common_firewall_rules[0].name.value
│     ├────────────────
│     │ var.common_firewall_rules is object with 3 attributes
│ 
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value. An
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`common_firewall_rules` is a map, not an array. You can't access a map using `[0]`. Your code would need to look like:

```
ipv4_firewall_rule {
    name        = var.common_firewall_rules["IP_Orange"].name
    range_start = var.common_firewall_rules["IP_Orange"].start_ip_address
    range_end   = var.common_firewall_rules["IP_Orange"].end_ip_address
  }
```

---

It's not clear why you are adding `.value` to try to reference the values of a map. That's not valid HCL.

It's also not clear why you would define that variable as a map. You could simplify things by making it a list:

```
common_firewall_rules = [
        {
                name             = "Orange"
                start_ip_address = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
                end_ip_address   = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
        },
        {
                name             = "OBS2"
                start_ip_address = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
                end_ip_address   = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
        },
        {
                name             = "OBS2"
                start_ip_address = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
                end_ip_address   = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
        }
]
```

---

Either way, you can use a dynamic block to simplify your code:

```
 dynamic "ipv4_firewall_rule" {
    for_each = var.common_firewall_rules

    content: {
        name        = ipv4_firewall_rule.value["name"]
        range_start = ipv4_firewall_rule.value["start_ip_address"]
        range_end   = ipv4_firewall_rule.value["end_ip_address"]
    }
  }
```